# ARRAY declaration inside function in db2 iseries 7.1

Tags: db2, db2-400

I am unable to declare an array inside a function. It shows the below error.

> Error: [SQ20441] Array type not valid where specified.

My code is below,

```
CREATE TYPE REV_QTY AS INTEGER ARRAY[] ;--ALLOW_ARRAY_VALUE_CHANGES 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_REV_QTY (IN_IPID INTEGER,QTY_TO_PLACE  
   INTEGER,INITIAL_REV_QTY INTEGER)
RETURNS INTEGER
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA

--CONTAINS SQL
--RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN

DECLARE AVAILABLE_REV_QTY REV_QTY;
if exists(AVAILABLE_REV_QTY[IN_IPID]) then
CASE WHEN QTY_TO_PLACE > AVAILABLE_REV_QTY[IN_IPID] THEN 
    SET AVAILABLE_REV_QTY[IN_IPID] = 0
WHEN QTY_TO_PLACE < AVAILABLE_REV_QTY[IN_IPID] AND QTY_TO_PLACE >= 0    
THEN
    SET AVAILABLE_REV_QTY[IN_IPID] =  AVAILABLE_REV_QTY[IN_IPID] -  
QTY_TO_PLACE
END;
     END IF;
 RETURN AVAILABLE_REV_QTY[IN_IPID] ;
 END |
```

Please help me on this. I am new to DB2 i7.1 and I am unable to 
      understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Did you see the explanation of SQ20441 in the manual?

Comment: Yes. it says like  Array types can only be used:
1. As an argument of as SQL scalar function or an SQL or JAVA procedure.
2. For an SQL variable declared in an SQL procedure or SQL scalar function.
3. In a CAST specification in an SQL procedure or SQL scalar function.
The data type of the array type that is used when a routine is invoked must match the data
type of the array that was used when the routine was created.

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong manual.

Comment: Have you worked on this kind of scenario. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

The IBM i 7.1 documentation for that sqlcode=-20441 does not list\include the SQL Scalar Function as *where* an array-type specification can be made [neither as an argument nor declared variable].  See:

[**Listing of SQL messages**
These tables list SQL messages. Use these tables to find message text, cause text, recovery text, and corresponding SQLCODEs and SQLSTATEs.](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzala/rzalaml.htm)

> SQ20441
>   Message Text: Array type not valid where specified.
>   Cause Text: An array type was used but is not allowed in the specified context. Array types can only be used:
>
> • As an argument of an SQL or JAVA procedure.
>     • For an SQL variable declared in an SQL procedure.
>     • In a CAST specification in an SQL procedure.
>
> Recovery Text: Remove the reference to the array type. Try the request again.
>   SQLCODE or SQLCODEs: -20441
>   SQLSTATE or SQLSTATEs: 428H2

As asides, if the references were code where allowed:

• the EXISTS predicate is not allowed syntax as written in the OP; presumably the following predicate is desired:

`if cardinality(AVAILABLE_REV_QTY) >= IN_IPID then`

• required semicolon after the statements in `THEN` of `CASE` are missing

• `INITIAL_REV_QTY  INTEGER` is unreferenced

• `DECLARE AVAILABLE_REV_QTY REV_QTY ;` has `DEFAULT NULL` so even the `CARDINALITY` is of no use unless the array values are first constructed; perhaps passed as an argument

Note: the work of the routine could be composed as a SQL `PROCEDURE`, and perhaps that `FUNCTION` also could be rewritten to invoke the stored procedure to perform the array work -- unsure, as whence the data comes for the array is not clear from the OP.